# I'm trying to change the Textual Content on React Webpage when it's ready to print on browser window

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events

what I'm trying to achieve is, I'm trying to change the content of a react webpage when it's Transpile from JSX to traditional HTML and ready to print on the browser window. but the tricky thing is I want to change the content on the basis of previous content like

For example: if there is an element p with innerHTML "Change Me!", I want to select the "p" tag by getElementByTagName and check whether its innerHTML is "Change Me!" if yes I'll replace it with new text otherwise I'll skip it.

the problem is, that React Injects the components into the root element when the DOM is ready. I tried window events like Onload, Onbeforeprint, and DOMContentLoaded but the webpage loads with Old Text, and new Text never replaces the old.

Comment: So you have a React (built with CRA most likely) application, and some how have to modify the content without modifying the source code of the React app?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Without changing the source code. if we just add a script in index.html that changes the content of the app before it renders on the browser.